# Reset password in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, mongoose

Im trying to add reset password feature.User enters username,email and full name,when these values match data from database ,password is changed,otherwise an error is shown.
This is what im doing-

```
app.post("/reset",function(req,res){
User.findByUsername(req.body.username).then(function(sanitizedUser){
if (sanitizedUser){
    sanitizedUser.setPassword(req.body.password, function(){
        sanitizedUser.save();
        req.flash("success","password resetted");
            res.redirect("/login");
    });
} else {
    req.flash("error","User doesnt exist");
            res.redirect("/reset");
}
},function(err){
    console.log(err);res.redirect("/");
});

});
```

But i want to compare more than just the username,i want to compare email and name of the user too.And when i add-
`User.find({username:req.body.username},{email:req.body.email},{name:req.body.name})`and enter some wrong data,the page just keeps reloading rather than showing an error.
What changes should i make to do that?Please help.

Im using express,nodejs,mongodb

Comment: Are you using Passport? http://passportjs.org/

Comment: Yes,im using Passport @DanGreen-Leipciger

Answer (score 1):

You have a **redirect loop**.

In the case of `!sanitizedUser` you redirect to the same page `res.redirect('/reset')`.

This is causing your page to keep reloading.

You should change the line:

`res.redirect('/reset')`

to

`res.status(500).send('Some useful error message')`

Comment: its still not working,btw did you take that into consideration that im using multiple creteria for searching (as i mentioned at the end of question)

Comment: Have you tried with the values hard coded? i.e. User.find({username:"dan"},{email:"foo@bar.com"},{name:"Dan Green-Leipciger"})?

Comment: How can i try that? if i change the code as you said,the password might change ,but how would i know,since password is saved as some salt and hash

Comment: First of all, you should not be touching the password here. You need to email a reset token with an expiry time. Have the user click a link with that token as a get parameter, check for that in your route and only then allow them to reset the password.

Comment: yes,the hash and salt changed ,i think that means the password changed

Comment: Is your question about passport, mongo, or express?

Comment: But that would make the problem more complex,this way it is easier,and im satisfied with this security

Comment: What is your questions?

Comment: How to add multiple creteria to search for a user (not just username)..cuz when im adding multiple creteria,the page just keeps loading irrespective of,the data is matching the data from database or not

Comment: Run this: User.find({username:"ACTUAL_USERNAME"},{email:"ACTUAL_EMAIL"},{name:"ACTUAL_NAME"}).  If it works, the problem is in your request.

Comment: So, go debug it. The problem is in your query.

Comment: Are you using mongodb nodejs driver??If so, try User.find({username:"ACTUAL_USERNAME",email:"ACTUAL_EMAIL"‌​,name:"ACTUAL_NAME‌​"})

Comment: I think he's using mongoose

Answer (score 0):

```
if(req.body.username && req.body.email && req.body.name && req.body.password){

    //add logic to hash password below
    let hashedPassword = req.body.password;


    Model.findOneAndUpdate(
        { username : req.body.username, email : req.body.email, name : req.body.name },
        { "$set" : { password : hashedPassword } },
        //if below option "new" is set to true, call back will return new document else it will return old document beforeupdate
        { new : true },
        //call back
        function(err, person){
            if(err){
                //err found
                res.send(err);
            }
            else{
                // no error and also person exists
                res.send('Password successfully updated..');
            }
        }
    );
}
else{
    res.send('Please provide all details..');
}
```

Comment: It is showing 'Password successfully updated..',but the new password doesnt work and the old one does

Comment: If you do console.log(person)  in success Else part,  do u get a person object? Which password does it show?

Comment: And also i noticed that after changing the password,now i can see the password in normal english when i find the user in mongodb,before it just used to show salt and hash

Comment: The commend where I have mentioned add logic for hash password, you need to get hashed password in there so that it will be saved in encrypted format in dB..

Comment: Okay.Is that also the reason that the new password isnt getting saved?

Comment: As you mentioned above your password is getting saved as normal english. So i guess your password is getting saved. It does not depend on if it is hashed or not.

Comment: i used var hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate(req.body.password); to hash it,this makes password hashed,but still it is storing password as "somestringhash",while before it didnt used to show password at all,only salt and hash were shown.Plus even if i enter wrong data it shows password successfully changed and new password isnt working either (when i enter correct data)

Comment: Can you help? please

Comment: @RaviHooda are you using brypt for hashing the password?

Comment: No,im using password-hash

Comment: Can you please explain what issues you are facing currently? I would be happy to help you. Basically its correct that the password are getting stored as encrypted hash in database.

Comment: it shows password successfully changed but nothing happens,and even if i enter wrong details it shows success msg .Also i have noticed that before, in database there was no password field ,only hash and salt were there.Now it shows password field with value equal to a hashed string.

Comment: Ohh alright so you had different schema. Then you can try  { "$set" : { hash : yourhash , salt : yoursalt} } which will be like your old schema

Comment: You can use password-hash to get the hash and salt from the password from request and then save it like above

Comment: before it was like {"_id":some id,"username":abc,"salt":randomstring,"hash":randomstring} and now if i change a password it adds another field to it "password":hashed string,i think the new password isn't overwriting the previous one it just saves it as some other field

Comment: Im now using bcrypt, it has solved problem of separate password field.But it still doesnt work.The new salt and hash are smaller in size'than the original ones which are much longer,can that be a problem? And also even if i put wrong data it shows "password successfully updated"