# Adding data to database only when it is not already present (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Im trying to add new data to database ,only if it isn't already present.I ask user to enter name ,and if the name already exists he/she can't enter corresponding data,and an error is to be shown saying it "already exists".
This is what im doing-

```
app.post("/new",function(req,res){
    Model.find({"name":req.body.name},function(err,persons){
         if(err!=null)
            { req.flash("error","Already Exists");
              res.redirect("/new");}
         if(err==null)
            { Model.create(req.body.person,function(err,newPerson){
                    if(err){console.log("Error");}
                    else{
                    newPerson.name=req.user.name;
                    newPerson.id=req.user._id;
                    newPerson.save();
                    res.redirect("/");}

            });}
    });

});
```

But when i use this,even though i enter already present data,it still adds it to the database.
Im using express,node js and mongodb

Comment: When `Model.find` doesn't find a document, `err` will be set? That sounds slightly counter intuitive. Are you sure that's what really happens?

Comment: I think it is correct @mingos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.findOne({"name":req.body.name},function(err,person){
    if(err){
        //err found
        res.send(err)
    }
    else if(person){
        // no error and also person exists
        req.flash("error","Already Exists");
        res.redirect("/new");
    }
    else{
        // no error and and person not found so create new one
        let newPerson = new Model({
            name : req.body.name,
            otherParams : req.body.otherParams 
        });
        newPerson.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send('could not create new person');
            }
            else{
                res.send('person created successfully');

            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Glad to help you, Cheers mate :)

Comment: can you please help in this too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640381/reset-password-in-node-js

Comment: @RaviHooda answered that one too :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you tried it to do with your mongo schema field like,

```
name: {
     // other rules
     unique: true 
},
```

On new creation, it will generate `error` object in callback if already exist.

This will also reduce your `find` database call.

Comment: @Harish please include a bit more code into your answer, so that Ravi is able to understand...

Comment: I did check it,i just had to add the unique rule in the schema right? Thatswhat i did,but it didnt work @Jonasw

Comment: @RaviHooda you just need the Model.create() call, then on error show the *already exists* ...

Answer (score 0):

Add the options-object ( http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate )

```
Model.findOne({"name":req.body.name}, {upsert:true},function(err,persons){
     if(err!=null)
        { req.flash("error","Already Exists");
          res.redirect("/new");}

});
```

Comment: Sorry didn't checked your callback.
Your err is null, except a big database error occurs not if he finds a row. So just delete your if(err==null)
I updated my answer

Comment: Sorry,but it stills add the data to the database without any error

Comment: Do you want me to just remove the creating part? How would that help?